How to add additional CSS properties to card input fields for securedfields
I haven't been able to find a way to add pseudo classes to the card input fields; namely :hover and :focus.
There is no mention of this in the styles property in the AdyenCheckout instance.
Essentially, what I would like to do is to change the CSS outline property when the input field is in a focus state. Moreover, I am not using the Drop-in component and am building a custom component. Hence, it is inside an iframe.
Please advise.

There are 2 options to customise the card component (and Drop-in).
Define your custom Drop-in CSS classes and style as you need:
# define outline upon focus
.adyen-checkout__input--focus {
  outline: 4px solid orange;
}

Style card input fields using the StyleObject
const configuration = {
  //...other configuration parameters
  paymentMethodsConfiguration: {
    card: {
      styles: {
         base: {
          color: "#ffffff",
          fontSize: '16px'
        }
      } 
    }
  },
};

The second approach is what you can use to change the styling of the card number, CVC, and expiry date of a card.
const styleObject = {
  base: {
    color: 'purple',
    fontSize: '32px',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica'
  },
  error: {
    color: 'red'
  },
  placeholder: {
    color: '#ffffaa'
  },
  validated: {
    color: 'green'
  }
};


Hey @Beppe C, the issue is I am attempting to build a custom UI component. I would like to change the outline property on focus, but have yet to be able to do so

You can, customising the class .adyen-checkout__input--focus. I have edited the answer.

Hi @Beppe C, as the input field is inside an iframe, I don't think it's as simple as targeting the class.

In this case you style the secured fields wrapper, outside the iframe. I was able to do it on my local implementation.

Are you referring to the <span /> element with the data-cse attribute?

If that's the case, I was only able to get the hover state working

I can get the hover state, but not onFocus. Would appreciate a link to your working example

See here https://github.com/gcatanese/adyen-node-online-payments/tree/css-focus/checkout-example

Thanks, but this would not work with my example
